# Day select option not validating onsubmit

Tags: javascript, validation, html-select

First of all I'm new to Javascript and html.

I'm having a issue with validating a modal popup enquiry form for required fields. I've managed to implement a enquiryFormValidation javascript function on submittion of the form. But for some reason within the function details div the day dropdown selection box is not validating.

Your thoughts and suggestions are welcome....

Here's the JavaScript:

```
// Enquiry Form Validation

function enquiryFormValidation() {

// Setting Variables

var errormessage = "";

var ufirstname = document.getElementById("firstname");
var usurname = document.getElementById("surname"); 
var uaddress = document.getElementById("address");
var upostcode = document.getElementById("postcode");
var utel = document.getElementById("tel");
var uemail = document.getElementById("email");
var uhearabout = document.getElementById("where");
var fday = document.getElementById("fday");
var fmonth = document.getElementById("month");
var fyear = document.getElementById("year");
var vname = document.getElementById("vname");
var vaddress = document.getElementById("vaddress");
var vpostcode = document.getElementById("vpostcode"); 
var ftype = document.getElementById("ftype");
var noattend = document.getElementById("noattend");
var arrive = document.getElementById("arrive");
var garrival = document.getElementById("garrival");
var fend = document.getElementById("fend");
var addinfo = document.getElementById("additional-info-textarea");


// Form submit required fields validation



if   (ufirstname.value == "(e.g. John)") {
    errormessage += "Please enter your Firstname.\n";
    ufirstname.style.border = "1px solid red" ;

 }

if   (usurname.value == "(e.g. Smith)") {
    errormessage += "Please enter your Surname.\n";
    usurname.style.border = "1px solid red" ;

 }

if   (uaddress.value == "(e.g. 101 Glimmer Street)") {
    errormessage += "Please enter your Address.\n";
    uaddress.style.border = "1px solid red" ;

 }

if   (upostcode.value == "(e.g. TF1 7HU)") {
    errormessage += "Please enter your Postcode.\n";
    upostcode.style.border = "1px solid red" ;

 }   

if   (uemail.value == "(e.g. info@glimmer-nights.co.uk)") {
    errormessage += "Please enter your Email.\n";
    uemail.style.border = "1px solid red" ;

 }   

if   (uhearabout.value == "blank") {
    errormessage += "Please select where you heard about us.\n";
    uhearabout.style.border = "1px solid red" ;

 }

if   (fday.value == "blank") {
    errormessage += "Please select a Function Day.\n";
    fday.style.border = "1px solid red" ;

 }


if   (fmonth.value == "blank") {
    errormessage += "Please select Function Month.\n";
    fmonth.style.border = "1px solid red" ;

 }   

if   (fyear.value == "blank") {
    errormessage += "Please select Function Year.\n";
    fyear.style.border = "1px solid red" ;

 }   

if   (ftype.value == "blank") {
    errormessage += "Please select a Function Type.\n";
    ftype.style.border = "1px solid red" ;

 }   


if   (garrival.value == "hh:mm") {
    errormessage += "Please select Guest Arrival time.\n";
    garrival.style.border = "1px solid red" ;

 }  


if   (fend.value == "hh:mm") {
    errormessage += "Please select Function End time.\n";
    fend.style.border = "1px solid red" ;

 }



if   (errormessage != "") {
    alert (errormessage);
    return false;

 }



} // End of enquiryForm-validation function
```

And here's the HTML:

```
                        <label for="fdate">*Date:</label>
                    <select size="1" name="fdetail" id="fday" class="input" tabindex="8" />
                                        <option vaule="blank">Day</option>
                                        <option value="01">01</option>
                                        <option value="02">02</option>
                                        <option value="03">03</option>
                                        <option value="04">04</option>
                                        <option value="05">05</option>
                                        <option value="06">06</option>
                                        <option value="07">07</option>
                                        <option value="08">08</option>
                                        <option value="09">09</option>
                                        <option value="10">10</option>
                                        <option value="11">11</option>
                                        <option value="12">12</option>
                                        <option value="13">13</option>
                                        <option value="14">14</option>
                                        <option value="15">15</option>
                                        <option value="16">16</option>
                                        <option value="17">17</option>
                                        <option value="18">18</option>
                                        <option value="19">19</option>
                                        <option value="20">20</option>
                                        <option value="21">21</option>
                                        <option value="22">22</option>
                                        <option value="23">23</option>
                                        <option value="24">24</option> 
                                        <option value="25">25</option>
                                        <option value="26">26</option>
                                        <option value="27">27</option>
                                        <option value="28">28</option>
                                        <option value="29">29</option>
                                        <option value="30">30</option>
                                        <option value="31">31</option>
                                    </select>
```

Comment: Please post a specific code on where you have a problem

Comment: HTML section updated with specific code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it like this

```
if (fday.options[fday.selectedIndex].value == "blank") {
    errormessage += "Please select a Function Day.\n";
    fday.style.border = "1px solid red" ;
 }
```

Correct the typo in your html as well.

```
<option vaule="blank">Day</option>
```

should be:

```
<option value="blank">Day</option>
```

Also,
[jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

Comment: Superstar.... I've been looking at this code for hours! Just to confirm, am I coding this correctly or would there be a more efficient way of doing it. Thanks in advance

Comment: There would certainly be a more efficient way of doing this. But you must learn to walk before you can run -> http://jquery.com/

Comment: @user2428136 make sure to mark the question as answered by clicking the green arrow arrow next to my answer